# alienware shows power light and keyboard, screen stays blank

Tags: laptop, ubuntu-22.04, blank-screen

I have an old Alienware computer (model 15 R3) that I use for testing. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on it and it was great for running CUDA jobs.

Now after running the Phoronix test suite (or the latest upgrade with APT, both happened) it does not start any more. Nothing is shown on screen in terms of BIOS, grub or the Alienware logo.

The Power light is backlit and does come on, then goes off and back on again, after which it stays on. The keyboard backlighting also shows, and I can see that the screen is blank not off (it is lighter than when the power is turned off, but nothing is shown).

I've restarted while pressing [delete] and [F2] hundreds of times or keeping the [shift] key down. but other than seeing that it's on, I have not got any further signs of activity.

Does anyone know how to get into an Alienware machine in this state?

Comment: Certainly a hardware error, perhaps the PSU. A workshop would start swapping parts until it locates the bad one. But we can't analyze your hardware over the internet.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. I thought, because all the hardware does turn on (including the screen), that I may still get in with a magical key combination or something similar. But you if you're this certain then we may need to open it up...

Comment: @alle_meije Have you tried a motherboard hard reset? To do so, unplug the AC adapter, disconnect the battery, repeatedly press the power button for 30s, hook everything back up and power on _(if that doesn't resolve, try the same again, but this time disconnect the CMOS battery before repeatedly pressing the power button)_. There is a button combination that can be held while the system is off and while pressing the power button that will force the system into hardware diagnostics mode, but I can't recall the button combination _(IIRC it involves the `Fn` key)_

Comment: Thanks! So a hard reset involves pressing the power button while the battery is out and the power is not connected either? It sounds a bit strange but I'm prepared to try anything.